# Dlink Dir-859 firmware upgrade bricked my router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I went to hook up my Dlink AC1750 Dir-859 router to my modem today to setup my wireless. Everything was fine, then I went to upgrade the router with the provided firmware from http://dlinkrouter.local./ which is the router itself. My I waited and waited, and now my router has a flashing green power light, and I've tried doing a factory reset as well as a recovery mode, and they both won't work. I press the reset button for the set amount of time I read online, and it continously has the green power light blinking. Looking for some help, or confirmation that my router is bricked. Thank you in advance.

OS: Windows 10

Router: Dlink Dir-859

[https://www.google.ca/search?q=dlink+dir-859&oq=dlink+dir-859&](https://www.google.ca/search?q=dlink%20dir-859&oq=dlink%20dir-859&)

ISP: Cogeco Canada

Answer (score 2):

User chrnod writes the steps for firmware recovery here 
https://forum.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=302529&view=next&sid=597969f62c75c8a1b189ba1ea18d2131

> 1st, you need to be wired connected to a lan port of your router.
>   then:  D-LINK all revert the same fashion. HOLD the reset button 30
>   seconds then power will blink. Set your ip to 192.168.0.2 and netmask
>   to 255.255.255.0 (on your NIC)then you try to access 192.168.0.1 and
>   you should have a special interface to upload the firmware 1.04 you
>   will have download from the dlink website.

You will want to download the latest firmware file from D-Link, put the router in firmware recovery mode, set a static IP on your computer in the range 192.168.0.2-254 /24, then access the router recovery page with a browser at the IP address 192.168.0.1. There you can upload the firmware you downloaded.